# Change Item order using _layouts/reorder.aspx?List=[GUID] in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Is there any way to set list item order in sharepoint list in selected list **subfolder** using build in reordering page?

Answer (score 2):

After reflection

```
// Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ReorderPage
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

and

```
SPUtility.GetUrlKeyValue
```

and

```
internal static bool LocateUrlKeyValue(string url, string keyName, out int start, out int ndx2)
```

the solution is to construct url passinf root folder like this

```
http://dev2:8080/_layouts/reorder.aspx?List=0d23c644-4538-48b1-a478-9eb7c3b363cc&Source=?RootFolder=/Lists/AgreementInvoicePositions/Zlotow/10731
```

Source parameter is important
Source=**?RootFolder**=/Lists/AgreementInvoicePositions/Zlotow/10731